# Datastage: how to improve the performance load data from oracle to sql server

Tags: datastage

The platform is `IBM Datastage 8.1 RHEL4 16G MEM,4CPU16CORE`. When I try to create a job to load data from Oracle to SQL Server the job is running correctly, but slowly. The row count from the source table in Oracle is about 100,000,000 and the speed load is only 620/s.

**How can i improve the load speed in this job?**

The flow is below:

```
oracle EE stage -->  odbc stage [config the sqlserver odbc in .odbc.ini]
```

The odbc config:

```
Driver=/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/branded_odbc/lib/VMmsss23.so
IANAAppCodePage=113
Description=DataDirect SQL Server Wire Protocol driver
Database=test
LogonID=datastage
Password=datacenter
Address=127.1.2.3,1433
QuotedId=No
AnsiNPW=No
```

Comment: What kind of parallelization are you doing?

Comment: What's the meaning of parallel?I use default.apt file to configure the parallel the job.The default.apt.

Comment: How many nodes does your configuration have setup?

Comment: 8 nodes.I think parallel config is not the key point of improve the performance.

Answer (score 2):

- Check the bottleneck:

  1. Copy the source SQL and query in oracle client to see how many rows
     can it return.
  2. Insert into target table from a small table to see if insert is the bottleneck.
  3. If 1 and 2 are both not bottleneck, check if it is the complex computation in your transformer

From my experience, this is too slow comparing to you hardware, the most possible bottleneck
is the source SQL and you should look into tuning it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IBM Native Driver for SQL Server and turn on bulk loading. Rerun the job. Don't use a generic odbc driver. I think its named VMSSQL24.so

Comment: Hm on rhel they are probably named datadirect. But turn on bulk load and watch performance fly (compared).